# Can you authenticate into SSAS with AD LDS (ADAM) accounts?

Tags: sql-server-2008, active-directory, ssas, adam

I'm very new to AD LDS and experienced but not qualified with SSAS, so my apologies for my ignorances with these.

We have a couple implementations where we expose SSAS via an HTTPS proxy (msmdpump.dll) and currently we have a temporary domain setup handling this (where our end-users have a second account+creds to manage because of this = non-ideal). I want to move us towards a more permanent solution which I'm thinking of moving all authentication to AD LDS for our web apps, SSAS, and others. However, SSAS is where I'm concerned about this.

I know SSAS requires Windows Authentication and to play nicely, and that this ultimately means Active Directory will be involved.

**Is there a way to get this done with AD LDS instead of having to use a full AD DS implementation? If so, how?**

Comment: Seems to me that ServerFault would be a better place.

Comment: Okay, I've asked this question over at ServerFault as well. (Did I do this appropriately?)

http://serverfault.com/questions/126326/can-you-authenticate-into-ssas-with-ad-lds-adam-accounts

Comment: I could not find how to comment. What does "SSAS requires a full AD account for authentication" mean??? I am BI (SSAS) developer and work with MSSQLServer Developer Ed. SSAS on Windows XP Pro isolated machine without any AD Can I ask you to share with your experience on the reasons, difficulties why have you ended up with full AD DS?

Comment: We have gotten this to work with local Windows accounts, but we want a centralized authentication system to manage this, hence some kind of AD installation. We gave up due to the time it was taking to get AD-LDS working, so we went with regular AD-DS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We ended up just going with full AD-DS instead of AD-LDS.

Answer (score 1):

Nope, SSAS requires a full AD account for authentication.

Comment: Is this documented somewhere? Don't mean to be rude but I'd love it if I could have a link for me to refer to in my documentation. :-)